Using Windows Configuration Designer to pin apps to the taskbar
my department is working on rolling out new computers with Win 11 to our organization and as part of the base image we would like to unpin some default apps and repin others. The best way I've come across this in my research is with Windows Configuration Designer and a xml file.
I load the provisioning package and log into an account, file explorer is gone but outlook(new) remains with no apps I wanted pinned on the taskbar. I'm unsure why the provisioning package isn't applying the settings I want.
The xml file is loaded into Windows config under the Start tab and should be in the right spot
I believe I have the variables right based on this Microsoft link
The names of the apps I got from running a Get-StartApps | Format-List PS command
Here is the block of code I Have that should contain the desired settings
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
   xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
   xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
   xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
   Version="1">
 <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
   <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
     <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
       <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Windows.Explorer" />
       <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationID="Chrome" />
       <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.EXCEL.EXE.15" />
       <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15" />
       <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.WINWORD.EXE.15" />
   </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
</CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>

